# Validación de un elemento de un arreglo de cadenas, con una cadena ingresada por el usuario en C

Tags: array, c, string

```
//Tengo este código

char *nombres [] = {"Juan","Pedro","Santiago"};
char nombre_ingresado;

printf("INGRESE: ");
scanf("%[^\n]",&nombre_ingresado);

if(nombre_ingresado == nombres [1] ){
    printf("\nNombre ingresado valido");
}
```

Deseo comparar una cadena que el usuario ingrese, con el elemento numero 1 del arreglo, osea "Pedro" .

Pero el programa me da el siguiente error:

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

En esta línea

```
if( nombre_ingresado == nombres [1] ) {  // <-- AQUI
    printf( "\nNombre ingresado Valido" );
}
```

¿A que se debe? ¿Cómo puedo arreglar mi programa?

Comment: ¿ Podrías indicar el error exacto que te da ? Para completar la pregunta y que sea fácil de encontrar por otros :-)

Comment: este es el error:


ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una *traducción libre* del error podría ser:

> El estandar ISO C++ prohibe la comparación entre un entero y un puntero.

Que es justamente lo que tú estas haciendo:

```
char *nombres [];
char nombre_ingresado;

...

nombre_ingresado == nombres [1]
```

Estas intentando comparar un entero (tipo `char`) con un puntero (tipo `char *`).

Tu problema es que un `char` es **un entero de 8bits**; lo que antiguamente podría considerarse un *caracter*. Y, por supuesto, no es capaz de almacenar una cadena de texto completa. De hecho, con los estandares actuales, solo puede almacenar ciertos caracteres básicos; ni siquiera puede almacenar una simple `ñ` (en UTF-8).

Con algunas correcciones, tu código quedaría así:

```
#include <string.h>

char *nombres [] = { "Juan", "Pedro", "Santiago" };
char nombre_ingresado[100];

printf( "INGRESE: " );
scanf( "%100s\n", nombre_ingresado );

if( !strcmp( nombre_ingresado, nombres[0] ) {
  printf( "\nNombre ingresado valido" );
}
```

Fíjate en los cambios:

1. `nombre_ingresado` pasa a ser una formación, no un simple `char`.
2. Comparamos las cadenas usando la función disponible a tal fin: `strcmp( )`.

<sub>Ya que estás en C++, podrías usar `std::istream` y `std::string`, lo cual facilitaría mucho las cosas. Estas usando las funciones *clásicas* de C, sin aprovechar la potencia de C++</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Hice algunas modificaciones a mi código y el resultado fue el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *nombres [] = { "Juan", "Pedro", "Santiago" };

char nombre_ingresado[10];

printf( "INGRESE: " );

scanf( "%s", nombre_ingresado );


if (strcmp(nombre_ingresado, nombres[1] == 0)) { 

  printf( "\nNombre ingresado valido" );

}
```

Donde la función **strcmp** retorna 0 si es valido, por lo tanto el programa ingresará a la condición if si ingreso la cadena "Pedro" e imprimirá: "Nombre ingresado Valido".

Gracias por sus aportes.